# html text input injected with javaScript is ignoring onclick material design css

Tags: javascript, css, material-design

I am doing a templating platform and I am using material design for the looks.
I just started coding the part where inputs are injected to the form. The thing is that I just started injecting text inputs and it looks as it should but the onclick css is not working! (The onclick css makes a blue line expand from the center of the text input, telling that the input is in focus)

This is how I am injecting the html:

```
document.getElementById("smallTextField").onclick = function () {
let div = document.getElementById("formContainer")
div.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", '<div class="col-sm-3">\n' +
    '                                    <div class="form-group">\n' +
    '                                        <div class="form-line" id="test">\n' +
    '                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="col-sm-3">\n' +
    '                                        </div>\n' +
    '                                    </div>\n' +
    '                                </div>');}
```

I hope you can understand my problem :/

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use jQuery, one option you have is to utilize the `$element.prepend()` function after binding to the `click` event.

```js
$('#smallTextField').on('click', function () {
    let $div = $('#formContainer');
    $div.prepend(
      '<div class="col-sm-3">\n' +
      '    <div class="form-group">' +
      '        <div class="form-line" id="test">' +
      '            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="col-sm-3" />' +
      '        </div>' +
      '    </div>' +
      '</div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="smallTextField" placeholder="smallTextField" />

<div id="formContainer"></div>
```